# Unable to find meaning of }); curly bracket, round bracket in Android

Tags: java, android

As a beginner in Android and having been away from programming for many years, I could not find an answer for this one on the internet. It involves the following code from a book I have been reading, but the syntax is common for Android. I couldn't work out what the }); represented. As someone who, in the past, has made an effort to make bracketing readable, I find this code amazing, surely a better way of showing this is possible?

Here's the code:

```java
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkAutosave);
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
            DisplayToast("CheckBox is checked");
        else
            DisplayToast("CheckBox is unchecked");
    }
});
```

Anyway does anyone know the meaning of the }); at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the close the definition of the anonymous implementation of `View.OnClickListener` and then to close the method call `setOnClickListener()`.

To make it more clear, the code is equivalent to:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
            DisplayToast("CheckBox is checked");
        else
            DisplayToast("CheckBox is unchecked");
    }
};

checkBox.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: +1 But be prepared in case the OP asks "What is the meaning of the `};` in your code example?"

Comment: I'm a dinosaur from before the OOP days :) Mark I'm assuming that the ; is the end of the View.OnclickListener instruction (thanks SteveR!). I did actually find an answer but it was so hard to search for when you're looking for symbols, so I thought I'd post and then answer, but you people are too quick! Thanks heaps. Hopefully the next newbie will find this quicker.

Answer (score 3):

in "});":

- "}" : close View.OnClickListener() method
- ")" : close setOnClickListener()
- ";" : close instruction

Answer (score 1):

It closes the setOnClickListener . TIP if you are using eclipse set your cursor to the right of the closed bracket.The open bracket will than be highlighted so you can see what's what.

Comment: Thanks androidcurious, for some reason I couldn't match the () brackets but I can match the {} OK. I'll check again.... yes you're right of course. I didn't see the matching bracket because it wasn't where I expected it! Selective blindness.

Comment: My matching brackets are now red so even I can see them.

Comment: Glad I could help. And yes, I don't think that you can use this trick on ()s

Comment: Hi @androidcurious, since the above post I've found that Eclipse Indigo works by matching both () as well as {}.

Answer (score 0):

Start:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
            DisplayToast("CheckBox is checked");
        else
            DisplayToast("CheckBox is unchecked");
    }
});
```

Eliminate method (this won't compile in all cases, but lets pretend it will for now):

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  /* .. */
});
```

Remove extra whitespace:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { /* .. */ });
```

And, there. It looks like a "normal method call" :) The code is just passing a *new* instance of *anonymous type* that represents an event listener.

It could have been written:

```
ClickEventListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() { /* .. */ };
checkBox.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those answers. I found rearranging the brackets helped so I'll post this for future reference. Though I'm not sure how it conforms to conventional practise.

```js
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkAutosave);
checkBox.setOnClickListener
    (   new View.OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                  if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
                      DisplayToast("CheckBox is checked");
                  else
                      DisplayToast("CheckBox is unchecked");
             }  // onClick
        } // new View.OnClickListener()
    );  // checkBox.setOnClickListener
```

Cheers!